# Definition of a sequence where the index number is not $0$ or $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, terminology

**A definition of a convergent sequence**: A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent with $L$, if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Normally the sequence starts with $a_0$ or $a_1$. Does the definition hold if $\{a_n\}_{n\geq k}$ for some fixed $k\geq 0$? I feel like the defintion needs to manipulate a little, so that $N$ is chosen with $n\geq N\geq k$ to make it sense.

For example, $a_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)(n-5)}$ for all $n\geq 6$. Since $a_n\leq \frac{1}{n-1}$ for all $n$, we can choose an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $N>1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. But this only works if $\epsilon\geq \frac{1}{5}$. What if $0<\epsilon< \frac{1}{5}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, with the minimal change that $N$ has to be at least the starting point of your sequence, say $k>0$.

You can also, if you sequence starts at $k$, just rederive it by consdering instead the sequence $(a')_{n\geq 0}$ defined
$$
a'_n = a_{n+k}
$$
for $n\geq 0$. Convergence, limit, etc. will be preserved.

---

As for your specific example: just choose $N > \max\left(6, 1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$. You do not have to choose the *smallest* $N>1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, just *any* such $N$: so $\max\left(6, 1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$ does the job and will deal with that issue.